# Prevent popup in Firefox if username/password are in URL

Tags: firefox, basic-authentication, firefox-profile

If you have a site protected with Basic authentication, you can automatically login if you add the username and password to the url

```
http://foo:bar@localhost
```

However, in Firefox, you will still get a popup

[image]

Is there a way in firefox to tell it not to show this dialog. For example, I can imagine that there is a setting inside the Profiles section to trust this site (which might solve this problem). Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: After a bit more searching I discovered that it might be possible with [network.http.phishy-userpass-length](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=979549), But when I check this in `about:config` I can't find it. So possibly this options has been removed

Comment: _“But when I check this in about:config I can't find it”_ – that’s presumably because the person there is talking about _adding_ it …

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that you can add properties yourself, thnx. However, I added this `network.http.phishy-userpass-length` with a value of 1024 and it doesn't work (I tried both `string` and `integer`)

Comment: Try setting the value to 255. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.phishy-userpass-length#Possible_values_and_their_effects

Comment: Yes now it works. I've deleted my profile and created a new one! It  also works now for 1024 :)

Answer (score 5):

Just ran over that question and it helped me. So here the solution, if someone else has the same issue:

1. open `about:config` in Firefox (confirm the message)
2. right mouse on the list: New - Integer
3. Set property name `network.http.phishy-userpass-length`
4. Set Value to `255`
5. restart Firefox

Answer (score 0):

The possibility to use login credential in the URL has been deprecated in Firefox:

> https://username:password@www.example.com/

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#access_using_credentials_in_the_url